# Could someone help me with THEMES in ubuntu 14.10 ,let's say NUMIX,GNOME........i feel very confused [non-duplicate]

Tags: gnome, themes, 14.10

i just now installed Ubuntu 14.10 in my laptop.I am a newbie to this sort of Dualbooting in a system,so i thought of giving all the applications a try therefore i installed all applications i found for this Operating system .
The only thing which confused me a lot is the THEMES for Ubuntu,by which you could change the icons,desktops,blah...blah..
So i installed NUMIX theme for Ubuntu,which was very nice in the screenshot mentioned in one website and even in the website of that particular company's.I did what i was supposed to do,but i DON'T know what to do to check out the installed themes....all i know is that it JUST GOT INSTALLED

[HELP ME OUT]

Answer (score 0):

To change themes and configure Unity desktop in general you need to install unity tweak

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

If you use Gnome-Shell instead of unity tweak, use gnoe tweak.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Comment: see @xangua ..i appreciate your help,but i wanna know the BASICS of using these THEMES.I mean i don't understand how to apply and run these themes and how to remove'em.So HELP me with that first,anyhow i installed the above mentioned applications